# Connection between firebase and vs code

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have downloaded the cli successfully but when I type...
flutterfire configure

I get this error even though I installed the latest version

the error message is

> i Found 0 Firebase projects.
> FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
> COMMAND: firebase --version
> ERROR: The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how to install it.

I have already created a project on Firebase

solve connection between firebase and vs code

I made it global

> C:\Users\gemy1>dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
> Package flutterfire_cli is currently active at version 0.2.7.
> The package flutterfire_cli is already activated at newest available version.
> To recompile executables, first run `dart pub global deactivate flutterfire_cli`.
> Installed executable flutterfire.
> Activated flutterfire_cli 0.2.7.

Comment: The error message pretty explicitly says what's wrong: it can't find a tool that it needs. Did you already follow the link in the error message, and follow the instructions given there?

Comment: Yes, I followed the link, deleted the program, and reinstalled it from scratch, as well as Firebase, but the problem was not solved.

Comment: Please edit your question to show exactly what you've done, as without that all we have to go on is what the error message says. While you're doing that, please replace the image of the error message with its actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Comment: In addition to creating a Firebase project, did you install the **Firebase** CLI too by following the instructions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli?

Comment: thanks for your time i solve it and I insert the solution

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that installing Firebase CLI using the binary file didn't work for me (even after Ventosus' answer), so here I do .

I had to install the Firebase CLI using the npm command (Node.js is required to use this command):

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

I've then been able to run the command: flutterfire configure